# Document rolling back unexpectedly?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, vba

In my office we store an Excel document on SharePoint for everybody to enter data onto as the days and weeks go. I am tasked with reviewing this data and making sure it correct each month. We had some issues from some of my coworkers being computer illiterate so I wrote a few macros to assist.

The macros are stored on the specific document and operate based on actions, such as: on new sheet, on close, on open, etc. I also wrote a macro that prompts the user to backup the document on close if the previous backup was over 4 hours ago. I added the backup functionality around 20th of this year.

So everything is working great and then sometime around Nov 20th I just check the folder where the backups are stored and it is missing a bunch of days. I open the file from SharePoint and the backup code is gone! It is the code as it was written before I added that functionality on Oct 20th. I ended up using some backups to fix everything and figured it was a one time hiccup, server reboot, or something.

Today, I checked the backup folder and the most recent backup was on Dec 1st. I opened the code and lo and behold it was the code from pre-Oct 20th! After reviewing the data it looks like on Nov 30th it reverted back to a Oct 17th version.

Any ideas or avenues to try and prevent this from happening a third time? I do not have admin access or anything on our office SharePoint.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

You could check if someone restores the excel document with the previous version.

And check if the issue occurs on the documents without the macros.

And in addition,  if you store documents with macros, the macros cannot be run when open the documents in browser.

More reference:

Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-F0DC28ED-B85D-4E1D-BE6D-5878005DB3B6